# Add colon to InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER keyboard

Tags: android, android-layout, android-keypad

How can I add colon(:) to the soft keyboard with the input type `InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER`
Currently I have the following code:

```
    NumberKeyListener keyListener = new NumberKeyListener() {
        public int getInputType() {
            return InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER;
        }

        @Override
        protected char[] getAcceptedChars() {
            return new char[] { '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '.', ':', '-', ',' };
        }
    };
    mytext.setKeyListener(keyListener);
```

But I also like the colon(:) on the number keyboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to change the characters on a soft keyboard, you need to create a custom IME. 

 [Android doc](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/creating-input-method.html)